# Wired LAN connection not working in Debian Wheezy on fresh install RTL8111

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, lan

I'm new-ish to linux so I'm not familiar with all the commands and settings. I've installed a fresh copy of LinuxCNC which came bundled within Debian Wheezy. No problems with install. My wired LAN connection says **disconnected**. My router seems to recognize the device from the control panel, but no internet connection from linux. The lights on the LAN port do light up and blink when the cable is connected.

I followed a few guides on editing the config file, but no luck. Then, I started with this guide:
[RTL8111 Linux Driver Guide](https://unixblogger.com/2016/08/11/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/)
but I am unable to get this machine on the internet to properly follow the instructions.

- 1) How can I diagnose the actual problem?(what commands?)
- 2) How can I fix it?

Per Comment:
Here's output:

```
me@debian:~$ lspci -knn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 16h Processor Root Complex [1022:1536]
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device [1019:9a3a]
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device [1002:9830]
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device [1019:9a3a]
00:01.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device [1002:9840]
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device [1019:9a3a]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 0 [1022:1538]
00:02.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1 [1022:1439]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:10.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller [1022:7814] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device [1019:9a3a]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:11.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1022:7801] (rev 40)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device [1019:7801]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:12.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller [1022:7807] (rev 39)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device [1019:9a3a]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd
00:12.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller [1022:7808] (rev 39)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device [1019:9a3a]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:13.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller [1022:7807] (rev 39)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device [1019:9a3a]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd
00:13.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller [1022:7808] (rev 39)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device [1019:9a3a]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:780b] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device [1019:9a3a]
    Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller [1022:780d] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device [1019:9a3a]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:780e] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device [1019:9a3a]
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 0 [1022:1530]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 1 [1022:1531]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 2 [1022:1532]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 3 [1022:1533]
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 4 [1022:1534]
    Kernel driver in use: fam15h_power
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 5 [1022:1535]
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device [1019:8116]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169



me@debian:~$ lspci | egrep -i 'network|ethernet'
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 0c)
me@debian:~$
```

Update:
I've downloaded the Driver from here: [RTL Driver](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2) Read the readme, Unpacked the tar and ran the autorun.sh file. I didn't get any errors. I rebooted the machine and I seem to have made some progress, I now see the connecting icon for the network, but I doesn't seem to actually connect to the network.

I've tried Static and DHCP with no luck. Oddly "debian" showed up on my router's list of connected devices when I tried static IP. I think I've got the right driver setup, but still cannot get connected.

Comment: Please edit and add the output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` and `lspci | egrep -i 'network|ethernet'`

Comment: @GAD3R output added. `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` did nothing, but `lspci -knn ' yielded an output

Comment: Run `update-initramfs` then connect the cable and run `dhclient eth0`

Comment: @GAD3R  Update-initramfs ="command not found"

Comment: Did you have synaptic package manager installed?  to install some package offline.

Comment: @GAD3R I do have it